# Python - Adding two dictionaries

Tags: python

How to add the values of two dictionary ?
Ex :

```
a = {'a':10,'b':11,'c':20}
b = {'a':1,'b':1,'c':1}
```

result must be

```
c = {'a':11,'b':12,'c':21}
```

Comment: generally when you ask a question you should include what you have tried and why it's not working. while some individuals may be happy to write code for you, stack overflow is not a code writing service..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily add two dictionaries by using **Counter** class of collections library for ex:

```
from collections import Counter

a = {'a':10,'b':11,'c':20}
b = {'a':1,'b':1,'c':1}

a = Counter(a)
b = Counter(b)
c = dict(a + b)
print c
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'c': 21, 'b': 12, 'a': 11}
```

Comment: zero values are getting lost if you would have in entry 'd':0 !!

Answer (score 1):

Next some please show some effort..

```
a = {'a':10,'b':11,'c':20}
b = {'a':1,'b':1,'c':1}

c = {k: a[k] + b[k] for k in a}  
print(c)  # {'c': 21, 'b': 12, 'a': 11}
```

The above works fine if we assume that `a` and `b` have the same keys.

If that is not the case, you can try the following:

```
a = {'a': 10, 'b': 11, 'c': 20, 'h': 5}
b = {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 12}

all_keys = set(a.keys())  # in Python 3 it can be simplified as `all_keys = set(a)`
all_keys.update(b.keys()) # in Python 3 it can be simplified as `all_keys.update(b)`
c = {k: a.get(k, 0) + b.get(k, 0) for k in all_keys}
print(c)  # {'c': 21, 'h': 5, 'a': 11, 'b': 12, 'd': 12}
```

Notice that i am using `get` on both dictionaries to skip the check on the existence of the key.

Comment: what if there is a key in `b` that is not in `a`?